# Will linux kernel 5 or above affect the memory release of go1.15?

Tags: go, memory, linux-kernel

**What version of Go are you using (go version)?**
go version 1.15

**Does this issue reproduce with the latest release?**
No

**What operating system and processor architecture are you using (go env)?**
Linux 5.4.54-1.0.0.std7c.el7.2.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Nov 16 10:02:20 CST 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

**What did you see instead?**
Below is a screenshot of the abnormal machine

**What did you do?**
The memory usage is too high, but there is no memory leak by analyzing the heap file of pprof.
The reason for this conclusion is:

1. My service is deployed on k8s, and there are other same services. The pprof file analysis results are similar to this problematic one (linux kernel version is 4.9.2-3.0.0.std7b.el7.5.x86_64 cmd/cgo: fails with gcc 4.4.1 #1 SMP Thu Apr 26 17:33:02 CST 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux).
2. I refer to the MADV_FREE problem in the link below. By analyzing the LazyFree of the /proc/1/smaps file, I found that it is all 0, and all machines are linux kernel 4.5 or above. Logically, the same problem will occur, but it does not No. runtime: default to MADV_DONTNEED on Linux #42330
   gotrace records are normal

**What did you expect to see?**
Why is the memory usage of this service high? What impact does Linux kernel version 5 and above have on golang memory management?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUit3.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00DrM.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FWQ6.png)

Comment: Welcome! Can you please [edit] to add transcriptions of your images of text into actual text? [See here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why. See [/editing-help](/editing-help#code) for how to format code blocks. See also: [/editing-help#tables](/editing-help#tables).

Comment: Your post seems to match the format and content of a bug report, but StackOverflow is not for bug reporting or issue tracking. This would be better directed at the maintainers of Go and/or Linux.

Comment: Go 1.15 has been out of support for over a year: https://endoflife.date/go

Comment: Try with Go 1.18 or 1.19 to see if the problem occurs there too

Answer (score 3):

It's not related to the kernel version.

Go 1.15 used `MADV_FREE` by default to release memory. This memory was released very lazily by the kernel resulting in larger RSS until the memory was actually needed elsewhere. Hence RSS didn't reflect anything close to the Go programs actual usage.

Go 1.16+ defaults to using `MADV_DONTNEED`, which results in memory being released much more promptly by the kernel.

See https://go.dev/doc/go1.16#runtime for more details.

You can use the `GODEBUG=madvdontneed=1` environment variable on Go 1.15, or preferably upgrade to a supported version of Go (eg, Go 1.19). Go 1.20 will be released soon, so that would be a good target too.